# libinput-config-default folder in /downloads/

Tags: permissions, root

I was clearing out my downloads folder and I had a copy of the etc folder from the root. I'm not sure why I had a copy of the etc folder there, but I just went ahead and deleted it along with everything else that was in the downloads folder. I got a message saying the folder titled libinput-config-default was protected and I couldn't delete it. Upon getting this, I went and checked the original etc folder, and this folder isn't there. I tried to look up where the libinput-config-default folder is supposed to go, but I am not sure where it goes or how to move it. Can anyone help me with this?